# Jasper report net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: $F{id

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have faced org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file. exception while compiling the .jrxml file.

I have kept my jrxml file under the resources folder.

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:report.jrxml");
JasperReport report=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

while compiling it throw the below error

Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Premature end of file.

After try to fill the report i have facing the below issue.
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map,dataSource);

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: $F{id}
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.handleEvaluationException(JREvaluator.java:284)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:316)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:673)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:641)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1169)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:545)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:530)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:548)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2597)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:823)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:264)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:615)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:433)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:758)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1074)
    at com.kousik.formentrygst.service.ReportService.exportReport(ReportService.java:47)
    at com.kousik.formentrygst.controller.CalculationController.generateReport(CalculationController.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at report1_1591247150649_828124.evaluate(report1_1591247150649_828124:173)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:302)
    ... 69 more

Comment: What is a full stacktrace? It is better to post small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue

Comment: @AlexK I have changed my version to 6.12.2 it was resolved but i have faced another problem. I have edited the question with the same.

Comment: Something wrong with your template

Comment: @AlexK Can you please guide me the proper template tutorial.

Comment: [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) & [JasperReports - Configuration Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html)